# Set null variable value to a default in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, null, var

I have a variable with an array of values like so:

```
var discount = [0, 0, 0, 0, 11.45646584567458, 25, 50];
```

But I don't want to set a value for every coinciding value from another function used by the form.  So I want to set null to a default of 0.  I tried the following but it did not work.  Can someone give me a better solution for this?  Please keep it rather simple as I am new to javascript.

```
if(discount = null){
discount = 0
}
```

Comment: `if(discount === null){`

Comment: your condition is also transforming discount from an array to a number, maybe you should use `discount.push(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the assignment operator, `=`, instead of a comparison, `==`:

```
if (discount == null) {
    discount = 0;
}
```

Also, you're overwriting your array when you do that. If you want to add a value to the array, you can push it onto the end, e.g.,

```
if (someValue == null) {
    discount.push(0);
}
```

It's not clear what values you're trying to compare, though, and what you really want to do.